# Folder for custom php files on webserver for WordPress website

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have  a custom php file which contains code for inserting data into a custom table from a html form.

My question is where do I upload this php file on the web server in order for the form action ="insert_data.php" to run?

When I run the form and click the submit button I get Page not found which refers to the php file. Currently I have put the file in my theme folder.

Any help is appreciated.

David

Comment: Is it a custom html form?  The action should be relative to your current location on the site, just as any link is.  When not using the absolute URL in the case.  If you put that file in the root html folder `public_html` or `www` then you can just put the full URL `http://example.com/insert_data.php` etc..

Comment: Yes, it is a custom html form.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Just tried http://example.com/insert_data.php. Getting the same result.